# Serve TailwindCSS with django_plotly_dash

Tags: python, css, django, tailwind-css, plotly-dash

I have a Dash app in Django being served via [`django-plotly-dash`](https://github.com/GibbsConsulting/django-plotly-dash) and I'm using Tailwind for the styling across the site. Tailwind seems to be working everywhere except for the Dash app, where it is kind of working, but seems to be overwritten by the Bootstrap at some points.

I can see the Tailwind styling without any issues if I run the Dash app on its own, but not when embedded in Django.

Here's the view inside Django (and [the code for this basic example](https://github.com/hubbs5/tailwind-dash)):
[image: dash app not showing Tailwind]

And here it is (with garish colors to see the difference) while running Dash and Tailwind without Django:
[image: Ugly Dash app with Tailwind]

Some of the Tailwind styling is being applied, such as the `container mx-auto` bit of the Dash layout, but others (e.g. coloring) are being dropped.

Here's the code for the Dash app, which is split into `layout.py`, `callbacks.py`, and `dashboard.py`:

`layout.py`:

```
from dash import dcc, html

layout = html.Div(
    className="bg-green-100 container mx-auto my-auto px-15 py-5",
    children=[
        html.Div(
            className="bg-red-100 py-5",
            children=[
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id="symbol-input",
                    options=[
                        {"label": "Apple", "value": "AAPL"},
                        {"label": "Tesla", "value": "TSLA"},
                        {"label": "Meta", "value": "META"},
                        {"label": "Amazon", "value": "AMZN"}
                    ],
                    searchable=True,
                    value="AAPL",
                )
            ]),
        html.Div(
            className="max-w-full shadow-2xl rounded-lg border-3",
            id="price-chart"
        )
    ]
)
```

`callbacks.py`:

```
from dash import dcc, html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import yfinance as yf
import plotly.express as px

def register_callbacks(app):
    
    @app.callback(
        Output("price-chart", "children"),
        Input("symbol-input", "value"),
    )
    def get_data(symbol):
        df = yf.Ticker(symbol).history()
        fig = px.line(
            x=df.index,
            y=df.Close,
            title=f"Price for {symbol}",
            labels={
                "x": "Date",
                "y": "Price ($)",
            }
            )
        return dcc.Graph(
            id="price-chart-1",
            figure=fig
            )
```

`dashboard.py`:

```
from django_plotly_dash import DjangoDash
from .layout import layout
from .callbacks import register_callbacks

app = DjangoDash("Dashboard")
app.css.append_css({"external_url": "/static/css/output.css"})

app.layout = layout
register_callbacks(app)
```

The Tailwind CSS is in `/static/css/output.css` and is linked as the stylesheet in the `base.html`. To ensure it's working correctly in Django, I put a simple homepage up and copied code from [Tailwind's site](https://play.tailwindcss.com/) to confirm that it works. Again, it's partially coming through in the Dash app, but seems to get overwritten.

Comment: Yes, it's linked in the question (here: https://github.com/hubbs5/tailwind-dash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After viewing your repository, I think the problem is not that the Bootstrap CSS overrides the tailwind's one, the problem here is that the classes that you defined are simply **not scanned by Tailwindcss**. I'm going to assume that you generate the `output.css` using this command:

```
> npx tailwindcss -i ./static/css/input.css -o ./static/css/output.css --watch
```

If that's what you did to generate the CSS, then I can understand what's going on here. That's simply because of your `tailwind.config.js` file looks like this:

```
...
  content: [
    "./static/css/*.html",
    "./templates/*.html",
    "./static/css/*.js",
  ],
...
```

You said that `container`, `mx-auto` classes are applied, but not the color classes (e.g. `bg-green-100`, `bg-red-100`), that's simply because `container`, `mx-auto` classes are defined in one of `"./static/css/*.html", "./templates/*.html", "./static/css/*.js"`, while `bg-green-100`, `bg-red-100` are defined in other directory than those directories (it's defined in `apps\dashboard\layout.py`).

The easiest fix is to add the directories in which CSS classes need to be applied to the `tailwind.config.js` file, e.g.:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./static/css/*.html",
    "./templates/*.html",
    "./static/css/*.js",
    "./apps/**" // add this line
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

This will add all classes from any files or any files in `./apps` directory or subdirectories to the tailwindcss build process. Don't forget to run the tailwindcss cli command (the one I mentioned earlier) every time you run the server though.

Comment: Yes, I ran the `npx` command and got a different `output.css` (according to git). I guess the hot reload didn't pick up the change because now I see it after restarting again. Thanks!